# Time Distributed LSTM model accuracy and loss static

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am attempting to create a time-distributed LSTM model, however, it seems that the accuracy and loss are static. The model is for binary classification.

Model

```
document_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype="int32")
embedding_sequences =embedding_layer(document_input)
x = LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)(embedding_sequences)
x = LSTM(32)(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
doc_model = Model(document_input, x)
input_docs = Input(
            shape=(TIME_STEP, MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH), name="input_docs", dtype="int32"
        )

x = TimeDistributed(doc_model, name="token_embedding_model")(input_docs)
x = LSTM(32)(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
outputs = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = Model(input_docs, outputs)

opt = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LR, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.999)

model.compile(
            loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"]
        )
model.summary()
model.fit(x_train, y_train,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Output

```
Epoch 1/30
169/169 [==============================] - 11s 40ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5004 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.6022
Epoch 2/30
169/169 [==============================] - 5s 32ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.6022
Epoch 3/30
...
Epoch 29/30
169/169 [==============================] - 5s 32ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.6022
Epoch 30/30
169/169 [==============================] - 6s 33ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.6022
```

Things I have tried

- Reducing learning rate to really small values.
- Creating a simpler model using a single non-time distributed LSTM (which works fine).
- Feed the model small training sizes (Its accuracy still sticks), which means the model cannot overfit the training data?

**Misc Information**

- X_train shape: TensorShape([10, 30, 200])
- Y_train shape: TensorShape([10])

x_train[1, 29]

```
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(200,), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([2217,  707, 1226,  339,  383, 2259, 4526,  876, 9241,    1,   91,
         66, 1162,  221, 1232,  246,  243,  499, 5167,  221, 1817,  968,
         94,  126,  176,   75, 5198, 1075, 1232,  126,  652, 3218, 5514,
        246,   24,  891,  139,  157, 1122, 1048, 1351,  968, 1476,  126,
        252,    1,   31, 2217, 1347,   86,  246, 1232,  260,  115,  144,
        471,   67, 6447,  243,  105,    1, 2218,  375,  418, 1661, 2217,
        707, 1226,  339, 1202,  260, 7895, 8745,    1,    1,  791,  835,
        557,    1,  284,   96, 3725,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0])>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `categorical_crossentropy` instead of `binary_crossentropy` if you have a binary classification problem?

Comment: @claudia it's the same, bin cross ent is just a optimized version of cat cross ent

Comment: @claudia, you are right I can, of course, use `binary_crossentropy`; however, `categorical_crossentropy` is also a valid loss choice. From the Tensorflow documentation - Use this cross-entropy loss function when there are two or more label classes. 

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia No, it is not the same, what you said is completely incorrect. The two losses make different assumptions, using categorical cross-entropy in this case makes little sense.

Comment: How many classes do you have in this dataset?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy two classes are present

Comment: Then you should be using binary cross-entropy loss, since you have only one output neuron with sigmoid activation.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy binary crossentropy is just the log-like of a multiclass distribution instantiated with 2 possible outcomes, i'm definitely not incorrect https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260505/

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia You are incorrect because we are talking about keras losses here, there is a good reason why there are two losses, one for the binary case, and another for the categorical (multi-class) case. As you see in my previous comment, the problem here is using the incorrect loss, which would not happen if these were the same.